# Run MPI Application from Visual Studio 2017 with each process in a different cmd window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, terminal, mpi

Using Visual Studio 2017 I am trying to run a MPI Application which resembles a Spades game. Upon running it I want to open a cmd terminal for each of the 4 players so that each of them can input his card choice upon his turn to act.

I tried a ton of options, including going to Project Properties -> Debugging and changing the **Command** to `$(MSMPI_BIN)\mpiexec` and **Command Arguments** to `-np 4 "$(TargetPath)"` - see link below:

[Command and Command Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6EcC.png)

but, apart from getting 4 processes to run at the same time I still get a single terminal open which doesn't react to any of my keyboard input.

Is there any way to open 4 terminals using the Visual Studio debug? Or any other way? running "mpiexec.exe -np 4 MyExec.exe" in a cmd / bash provides the same result as above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: VS only runs `mpiexec`, it does not control how `mpiexec` runs the processes. You want `mpiexec` to do a strange thing. Probably, you should use some other way of IPC, and MPI is not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible.

I have tried to use `AllocConsole()` on an mpi test program  and each process returns an error because it considers that there is already a console attached to it.

In a way it seems logic because mpiexec will launch the processes and every stdout will directed to the same output (file or console), as for stdin you have to choose which process will handle it (judging by the manual https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man1/mpiexec.1.php -stdin option).

These redirections being surely managed by the process manager (https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions)

As @Evg said judging by "the Spades game" allusion I think MPI is not what you need. Maybe more unix domain socket. But they are other ways to do inter-process com (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)